# special vectorial product numpy

Tags: numpy

[ref question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmLZK.png)

Let's say I have vector s and I want to produce the matrix m (see image) with only numpy functions, how could I do that ? I imagined to transpose the vector s and to find a special product between s and s^t but I couldn't manage to find it. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I don't see "image" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an outer product:

```py
s = np.arange(3) # array([1, 2, 3])
np.multiply.outer(s,s)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks a lot !!